# django: Display anchor link on template using Jinja if statement

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset, django-filter

I made a friends system in Django. I created a profile model for every user and it has a friend field. I also created a friendrequest model to send and receive request. Everything works fine. On every user's profile(a model) I can see three options: Add friend, remove friend and cancel request. But I only wanna show the add friend link if the user who's profile I'm on is not a friend of mine. The same for remove friend and cancel request(if the FriendRequest object exists then display the cancel request). I tried to check if the user who's profile I'm on is a friend of mine, if he is, the profile should display a remove friend option but the thing is not working. Here's my code:

## My models.py:

```
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    desc = models.TextField(null=True)
    pfp = models.ImageField(default='social_media/images/profile.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(default='social_media/images/cover.jpg', upload_to='cover_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    friend = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='friended')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # set when created

    def __str__(self):
        return "From {}, to {}".format(self.from_user.username, self.to_user.username)
```

## My view to display the profile:

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request, user_id=None):
    button_status = 'none'
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    if user in request.user.friended.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'
    if user:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        Post = post.objects.order_by('-created')
        return render(request,'social_media/profile.html', {'Post':Post,'User':user})

@login_required
def send_request(request,id):
    from_user=request.user
    to_user=User.objects.get(id=id)
    freq=FriendRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_user=from_user,to_user=to_user)
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

@login_required
def remove_friend(request,id):
    user1=request.user
    user2=User.objects.get(id=id)
    user1.profile.friend.remove(user2)
    user2.profile.friend.remove(user1)
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

@login_required
def accept_request(request,id):
    freq=FriendRequest.objects.get(id=id)
    user1=request.user
    user2=freq.from_user
    user1.profile.friend.add(user2)
    user2.profile.friend.add(user1)
    freq.delete()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

## My Profile template:

```
                  <div class="right_details_user">
                        <div class="profile_status">
                              <div>Status: {{ User.status.status }}</div>
                        </div>
                        {% if not user.username == User.username %}
                        {% if button_status == 'not_friend' %}
                        <a href="{% url 'add-friend' User.id %}">Add Friend</a>
                        <br>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'remove-friend' User.id %}">Remove Friend</a>
                        <br>
                        {% endif %}
                        <a href="{% url 'cancel-request' User.id %}">Cancel Request</a>
                        <br>                        
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ User.friended.all }}
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this within your template.

```
{% if not User in request.user.friended.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'add-friend' User.id %}">Add Friend</a>
      <br>
   {% else %}
 <a href="{% url 'remove-friend' User.id %}">Remove Friend</a>
 <br>
 {% endif %}
```

EDIT:

You can check for the sent request like this.

```
def userprofile(request, user_id=None):
     user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
     Post = post.objects.order_by('-created')
     sent_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user)
     return render(request,'social_media/profile.html', {'Post':Post,'User':user, 'sent_request':sent_request})
```

Now in template.

```
{% if sent_request and not User in request.user.friended.all %}
  <a href="{% url 'cancel-request' User.id %}">Cancel Request</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks man that works! I also wanna check if there's a Friendrequest object to the user whos profile Im on so that I can show the cancel request button!

Comment: Man I still face the issues with Add friend and Remove friend anchors. Although, the cancel request works

Comment: what's the issues ?

Comment: Even if Im friends with the user I still see the Add friend anchor and not the Remove Friend anchor

Comment: Did you add the user to the friend list properly while adding the friend ? Can you show the view which performs this action ?

Comment: The accept and remove friend view is working. I still updated the views above.

Comment: You are not adding the user in the friend. you can add user in the friend like this `user1.profile.friend.add(user2)`